# Is there any package that I can use in react native to listen the user incoming messages in my app and it is working in latest react native app?

Tags: android, react-native, android-messaging

I am creating a app that fetch the user message and store in data base in react native. I try different package that listen the user incoming messages but they are not working. Can some one suggest some working package with source code. I will be glad

I try different package like react-native-android-sms- listener, react-native-android- otp- verify, but non of the package is working properly.